# Is there a way to change a user's password from within code?

Tags: linux, unix, change-password

Long story short, I'm trying to implement a password reset feature for a web app. Currently, I'm forking an instance of the `passwd` program and feeding the current and new passwords to it on stdin. This is less than elegant, and I'd rather not have to parse stderr for the error message when something goes wrong.

It looks like the only way to do this without forking an instance of `passwd` involves reading and re-writing the shadow password file. That seems a bit risky to me. Is there no [__passwd()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=functions-passwd-passwd-applid-verify-change-user-password) function for Linux?

Comment: In most modern Linux distributions [PAM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) is used for password management.

Comment: `passwd` is fo interactive passwords. Firstly use `chpasswd`. You can read `man shadow` and `man 5 shadow` and try `putspent()`.

Comment: Have you read the sources of `chpasswd` (or `passwd`)?  You just need to do the same thing.  But be careful with the parts of the code that need to run as privileged user!

Comment: You shouldn't need to parse `stderr` - just forward it unchanged to the user if `passwd`'s exit status is non-zero.

Comment: "This is less than elegant" Elegance is in the eye of the beholder. Forking processes that do one thing and do it well is exactly how Unix is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I'll look into chpasswd, it's likely a better choice. I also went with simply forwarding stderr to the user in case of a non-zero exit code. I did consider just calling `putspent()` and friends, but I'd rather not re-invent `passwd` and I'm well aware of the consequences of doing it wrong.

Comment: Ideally, programs like `passwd` would have provisions to make it easier to invoke from another program. E.g. there would be a "-q" option that removes extraneous prompts like "Enter password" and which would limit the output to necessary error messages only. And which would assign a different exit code to each error. In fact, the `passwd` man page does list a number of exit codes, but the list is incomplete; e.g. "password too short" has exit code 10 but this is not documented.